# Implementation of Ruby arrays

Tags: ruby, data-structures

Python lists are implemented by CPython as amortized arrays. How are are Ruby arrays implemented, and for which implementations?

EDIT:

Partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310015/ruby-array-internals).

Comment: The source code is available. Have you looked at it? Is there something in there that you don't understand?

Comment: Use the source, Luke: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c

Comment: @muistooshort Why don't you look at `array.c` and check for yourself? The source is legible, but the macros and multitude of stdlib wrappers doesn't make a quick read. (Besides which, I'm a C programmer, but not all newcomers to Ruby are.) This is the type of question that I would think a Rubyist can answer in an instant, but would take me significantly longer to research for each Ruby implementation. I can't comprehend the hostility and downvotes.

Comment: I have nominated this for reopening as this question is now the second link on google (after the source code) for "ruby dynamic array implementation".  Frankly, the question is a good one, and lots of people are now coming here and seeing this ridiculous close reason ("not a real question"? really?) and rant about lack of research (frankly, I'm not a fan of reading C implementations of complex data structures, and I don't think most people are... yet I'm sure most Ruby experts are well aware of how the basic data structures of their language work and could answer this in a heartbeat).